# Comparison between Nikon F - 301, F 55, F 50, and Canon A-1, t-80

Tags: nikon, film, camera, vintage, film-cameras

Can you give me a comparison (of performances, quality, and if you know of photos taken by you or people you know etc) between these cameras?

Here some specifications:
- [F-301](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Nikon_F-301_(N2000))
- [F 50](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Nikon_F50_(N50))
- [F 55](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Nikon_F55_(N55))
- [Canon A-1](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Canon_A-1)
- [Canon t-80](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Canon_T80)

Comment: It seems kind of unlikely that someone will have expertise and available personal samples in exactly those five cameras, but... good luck — maybe they're out there. Is there something more specific you're interested in that you haven't learned from the camera wiki site you link to?

Comment: Also a comparison based on their specs is useful for me! Or just some considerations about their quality according to common opinions etc

Comment: That's the part that confuses me — you've got pretty good information at those links. What are you missing? (Maybe it would also help to know why those five in specific, too.)

Comment: Those five specific simply because I want to buy a film camera and I saw some offers of them

Comment: What are you going to glean from sample images taken with these cameras? Ahead of any influence a camera body may have on images will be considerations like the lens used, film used, and photographer skill/vision. The camera body doesn't have so much significance in my opinion. It's just a light-tight box at the end of the day.

Comment: You have many different **generations** in that line-up. Huge difference in general use between autofocus and manual focus cameras. You're not even comparing apples to apples. Why not? Why are you considering cameras from different gens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering film cameras that are the ages of the models listed in the question the prime consideration should not be on a comparison of features, it should be focused on the **current condition** of each one. That will affect each one's usability or non-usability much more than their comparative specifications when they were new.

Comment: And what about external lens? Can we use all of them with lens we use for our dslr?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo That's a different question. In the case of the three Nikons, "maybe." In the case of the two Canons, "no." The two Canons use the FD mount. No Canon digital cameras us the FD mount, which was superseded by the EF mount in 1987 with the introduction of the EOS system..

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much